# Rails giving error in angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using rails 4.2.4 
Gem file

```
gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self

 */
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

I have installed these files by manually downloading those files and including it in my javascript folder .
1) angular-datatables.min.js 
2) angular-route.min.js 
3) jquery.dataTables.min.js 
4) routing.js 
5) ui-bootstrap-0.14.0.min.js 
6) ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

I don't know how to resolve this error actually I have never use angularjs But I need to include those files .My errors are

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverSide' of undefined
    at Object.f [as fromOptions] (angular-datatables.min.self-e164bdf0c2d9000c6262c232dc2dd041f3372c4d835392429a38b0919321ce99.js?bod…:7)
    at angular-datatables.min.self-e164bdf0c2d9000c6262c232dc2dd041f3372c4d835392429a38b0919321ce99.js?bod…:7
    at processQueue (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14793)
    at angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14809
    at Scope.$eval (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16053)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:15871)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16161)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1680)
    at Object.invoke (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:4524)
    at doBootstrap (angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1678)(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:12521(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:9293processQueue @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14801(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14809Scope.$eval @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16053Scope.$digest @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:15871Scope.$apply @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16161bootstrapApply @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1680invoke @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:4524doBootstrap @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1678bootstrap @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1698angularInit @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1592(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:29014fire @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3149self.fireWith @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3261jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3473completed @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3504
angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:10766 GET http://localhost:3000/devices/js/device.json 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:10766sendReq @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:10559serverRequest @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:10269processQueue @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14793(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:14809Scope.$eval @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16053Scope.$digest @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:15871Scope.$apply @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:16161bootstrapApply @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1680invoke @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:4524doBootstrap @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1678bootstrap @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1698angularInit @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:1592(anonymous function) @ angular.self-d7c642a2239d433e219a2df47d65f3290d6ec49b679e42a3c8e8099a4a86d8f0.js?body=1:29014fire @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3149self.fireWith @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3261jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3473completed @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3504
```

Comment: It seems like the errors and warnings are giving you quite a few clues about how you could resolve this yourself, have you tried any of the suggestions?

Comment: yeah but didn't work.

Comment: What did you try, and what happened when you tried it? See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading `angular-datatables` before `jquery.datatables` which is causing that issue.

You should move your downloaded files to `vendor/javascript` folder and then load them in the correct order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require angular-datatables.min
//= require_tree .
```